# how to fix error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' in a postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with this function, I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), 
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION insertar_evento()
returns TRIGGER AS $$
BEGINIF(tg_op = 'INSERT') then
  INSERT INTO jur_eventos
              (
                          titulo,
                          descripcion,
                          fecha_inicial,
                          hora_inicial,
                          fecha_final,
                          hora_final,
                          recurrencia,
                          periodo,
                          login_creacion,
                          login_asignado,
                          jur_procesojuridicoid,
                          jur_abogados_id,
                          asignacion,
                          fecha_recordar,
                          realizado,
                          procesojuridicoxaudiencia_id
              )
              VALUES
              (
                          new.titulo,
                          new.descripcion_audiencia,
                          new.fecha_audiencia,
                          new.hora_audiencia,
                          new.fecha_audiencia,
                          new.hora_audiencia,
                          'N',
                          'A',
                          new.login_creacion,
                          new.login_asignado,
                          new.jur_procesojuridico_id,
                          new.jur_abogado_id,
                          false,
                          new.fecha_recordar,
                          false,
                          new.id
              );ELSIF(tg_op = 'UPDATE') THEN UPDATE jur_eventos
  SET    descripcion = new.descripcion_audiencia,
         fecha_inicial = new.fecha_audiencia,
         hora_inicial =new.hora_audiencia,
         fecha_final = new.fecha_audiencia,
         hora_final=new.hora_audiencia,
         login_creacion = new.login_creacion,
         login_asignado = new.login_asignado ,
         jur_procesojuridicoid = new.jur_procesojuridico_id,
         jur_abogados_id = new.jur_abogado_id,
         fecha_recordar = new.fecha_recordar,
         realizado = new.cita_cumplida
  WHERE  procesojuridicoxaudiencia_id = old.id;
  ENDIF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insertar_evento_audiencia 
    after INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON jur_procesojuridicoxaudiencia FOR each row
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE
      insertar_evento();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `BEGINIF`. It's supposed to be two words: `BEGIN` and `IF`. They're not part of one phrase.

Also it's not `ENDIF`, it's `END IF`. That is one phrase.

Comment: friend thanks for replying I have separate `end if` and `begin if`, only that when copying the code was joined